# Python requests library: a response returns single quoted JSON

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm playing a little with [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) and requests.

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.get(self.url, params={'key': KEY, 'location': self.location, 'radius': self.radius, 'types': "airport"}, proxies=proxies)
```

`r` returns an HTTP Status 200, fine, but I'm confused by what `r.json()` returns compared to `r.content`.

Extract of `r.json()`:

> {u'html_attributions': [],
> u'next_page_token': u'CoQC-QAAABT4REkkX9NCxPWp0JcGK70kT4C-zM70b11btItnXiKLJKpr7l2GeiZeyL5y6NTDQA6ASDonIe5OcCrCsUXbK6W0Y09FqhP57ihFdQ7Bw1pGocLs_nAJodaS4U7goekbnKDlV3TaL8JMr4XpQBvlMN2dPvhFayU6RcF5kwvIm1YtucNOAUk-o4kOOziaJfeLqr3bk_Bq6DoCBwRmSEdZj34RmStdrX5RAirQiB2q_fHd6HPuHQzZ8EfdggqRLxpkFM1iRSnfls9WlgEJDxGB91ILpBsQE3oRFUoGoCfpYA-iW7E3uUD_ufby-JRqxgjD2isEIn8tntmFDjzQmjOraFQSEC6RFpAztLuk7l2ayfXsvw4aFO9gIhcXtG0LPucJkEa2nj3PxUDl',
> u'results': [{u'geometry': {u'location': {u'lat': -33.939923,
> u'lng': 151.175276}},

And here is an extract of `r.content`:

> '{\n   "html_attributions" : [],\n   "next_page_token" : "CoQC-QAAABT4REkkX9NCxPWp0JcGK70kT4C-zM70b11btItnXiKLJKpr7l2GeiZeyL5y6NTDQA6ASDonIe5OcCrCsUXbK6W0Y09FqhP57ihFdQ7Bw1pGocLs_nAJodaS4U7goekbnKDlV3TaL8JMr4Xp

So `r.content` has the double quotes like a "correct" JSON object, while `r.json()` seems to have *changed* all double-quotes in single-quotes.

Should I care about it or not?
I can still access `r.json()` contents fine, just wondered if this was normal for requests to return an object with single quotes.

Comment: The `json()` method doesn't give you raw JSON. It gives you a Python object (nested combinations of dicts and lists) representing one.

Comment: ```json.dumps(r.json())``` will give you valid JSON

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) method doesn't actually return JSON. It returns a Python **object** (read: *dictionary*) that contains the same information as the JSON data. When you print it out, the quotes are added for the sake of readability, they are not actually in your data.

> Should I care about it or not?

Not.

Comment: Should somebody care? Maybe. That depends what's being done with the output. If further processing is being done in code, operating on the dict will probably be fine. But if the output is being sent to a console, file, or another tool that expects properly formatted json using double quotes: yes, you should care. (json-prettify tools come to mind).

Comment: yeah u should care, when trying to insert it into MySQL for example to a json data type attribute => it will fail, because it's not a valid json

Comment: @lolo: if you're inserting it into a database that accepts JSON, you don't have to use the `json()` method, you can just insert the raw data. `.json()` doesn't mean "convert this to json", it means "decode this JSON data".

Answer (score 9):

Just use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) function in order to serialize a JSON object to a JSON formatted string.

Example:

```py
json_response = json.dumps(requests.get(xxx).json())
```

Comment: use ```json.dumps(resp.json())``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396827/dump-missing-1-required-positional-argument-fp-in-python-json

Answer (score 4):

Python uses single or double quotes for strings. By default, it'll display single quote for strings.
However, JSON specification only consider double quotes to mark strings.

Note that requests' `response.json()` will return *native Python types* which are slightly different from their JSON representation you can see with `response.content`.

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing the single quotes because you are looking at Python, not JSON.

Calling [`Response.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) attempts to parse the content of the Response as JSON. If it is successful, it will return a combination of *dicts*, *lists* and native Python *types* as @Two-Bit Alchemist alluded to in his comment.

Behind the scenes, The `json()` method is just calling `complexjson.loads()` on the response text ([see here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L782)). If you dig further to look at the `requests.compat` module to figure out what `complexjson` is, it is the `simplejson` package if it is importable on the system (i.e. installed) and the standard library `json` package otherwise ([see here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/compat.py#L24)). So, modulo considerations about the encoding, you can read a call to `Response.json` as equivalent to:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get(...)
json.loads(response.text)
```

### TL;DR

Nothing exciting is happening and no, what is returned from `Response.json()` is not intended to be valid JSON, but rather valid JSON transformed into Python *data structures* and *types*.