# dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp' in python json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to prettify the json format but i am getting this error:

```
import requests as tt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

get_url=tt.get("https://in.pinterest.com/search/pins/?rs=ac&len=2&q=batman%20motivation&eq=batman%20moti&etslf=5839&term_meta[]=batman%7Cautocomplete%7Cundefined&term_meta[]=motivation%7Cautocomplete%7Cundefined")
soup=BeautifulSoup(get_url.text,"html.parser")

select_css=soup.select("script#jsInit1")[0]
for i in select_css:
    print(json.dump(json.loads(i),indent=4,sort_keys=True))
```

Basically i want to extract this type of element :

```
'orig': {'width': 1080, 'url': '', 'height': 1349},
```

I know i can do this with

```
select_css.get('orig').get('url')
```

But i am not sure is this json element is nested element under any element ? That's why i am trying to prettify to get idea.

Comment: you want `dumps`, which dumps to a *string*, `dump` takes a buffer, i.e. a file-handler.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Use `json.dumps()` instead. `json.dump()` needs a file object and dump JSON to it.

Answer (score 10):

It worked when I replaced

```
json_dump = json.dump(data_set)
```

by

```
json_dump = json.dumps(data_set)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use json.dumps() instead. json.dump() needs a file object and dump JSON to it.